# Change a text input's placeholder with Bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

There are `text-left` and `text-right` classes in boostrap 4 to align text inside an input left or right.

But is there a bootstrapish way to just align the placeholder of input without changing the alignment of its text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a bootstrapish way to do that. But you can change alignment for placeholder only with the following CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* chrome, safari */
   text-align: right;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: right;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: right;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  /* Internet Explorer */
   text-align: right; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, this can solve the problem but I am looking for a bootstrap CSS class if there exists any.

Comment: Apparently there is no bootstrapish way to solve the problem, so I'm considering select this post as the answer.